# Expo unexpectedly renders component with previous path

Tags: react-native, expo

When I access /test2 using browser and navigate to /test1 by clicking `link to test1`, the below behavior was observed.

/app/test1.tsx

```
export default function Test1() {
  const path = usePathname();
  const [pathState, setPathState] = useState(path);
  console.log("path", path);  
  console.log("pathState", pathState);
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    </View>
  );
}
```

/app/test2.tsx

```
export default function Test2() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Link href="/test1">link to test1</Link>
    </View>
  );
}
```

#### Repro Steps

1. access /test2
2. click `link to test1`

#### Expected Behavior

logging the message in console

```
path /test1
pathState /test1
```

#### Actual Behavior

logging the message in console

```
path /test2
pathState /test2
path /test1
pathState /test2
```

So it looks like Test component is rendered before the pathname is updated.
This is inconvenient behavior especially when using path parameter like /app/test/[:id] and initializing state value by the params.